# BASIC: Understanding my own Ada code. Finding numbers that divide an integer without fractions

Tags: loops, numbers, procedure, ada, division

I'm supposed to code a procedure that finds all integers that evenly divide a number, and I've come up with a solution that works; unfortunately with my non-existent coding knowledge, I don't know *why* it works.

Here's the basic code:

```
Get(Number)
A:=1
for X in 1..Number-1 loop
   A:=A+1;
   C:=Number/A;
   if C*A = Number then
      Put(A)
   end if;
end loop;
```

I've edited out some pure puts for readability, I understand that `A` increases with 1 each step of the loop, but I don't quite understand what number `C` retains each loop. I've tried backtracking by printing it, and it goes between the values 2 and 1 for a value of 10 on the "number". Instead of being 1 or 2, I'd see it as being 10/1, 10/2, 10/3, 10/4, 10/5, 10/6 etc, meaning once we reach the if statement we'll just have, lets say, 10/4*A where A is 4 and viola we get 10 even though 10 isn't divisible by 4.

How is C updated, can anyone explain in simple terms?

Comment: I think I understand it now. Number/A isn't the exact calculation but a rounding of to the closest integer which is why C is 2 for A=2 and Number =5, but for larger A's the value of C goes to 1 because lets say 5/3 = 1.xx and so on. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, except it’s not the *closest* integer; the division rounds down. Might be easier to use the `rem` operator, see [ARM 4.5.5(6)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-4-5-5.html#p6)

Comment: Integer division truncates towards zero (which is not the same as rounding down when negative values are involved). Note that A is in 2 .. Number when it is used, so why not get rid of X and use A directly: `for A in 2 .. Number loop`? Number is always divisible by itself (unless you allow it to be zero), so there's no reason to check that, so `for A in 2 .. Number - 1 loop`, followed by putting Number. I second the suggestion to use `rem`.

Comment: thanks guys, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the integers to find must be positive. In that case, the type of `Number`, `A`, `C` and `X` could instead be `Positive`. If the input is not a positive number, then a `CONSTRAINT_ERROR` exception will be raised. This is safer: an exception clearly indicates that something went wrong, and it is better than returning an incorrect result.

Note that the program never tests whether `1` is a valid divisor, even though it is. This is because `A` is incremented at the beginning of the loop; since its starting value is `1`, the first checked value is `2`. In any case, it is better to use `X`, the loop's variable. On your program, it will take values ranging from `1` until `Number - 1`, both ends included. In addition, `X` will behave like a constant inside the loop body, which eliminates the risk of accidentally overwriting its value.

The value assigned to `C` is the result of dividing `Number` over `A`. Given that these variables are integers, the division result will be truncated. For positive numbers, this is equivalent to "rounding down" the result. If `Number` is evenly divided by `A`, then the remainder will be zero, so the multiplication will result in the original value. Otherwise, the remainder will be lost, so the value of `C * A` will be less than the value of `A`.

A simpler approach is to directly calculate the remainder of both numbers, and then check whether it is zero. This is the resulting code:

```
procedure Main is
   Number : Positive;
begin
   Get (Number);
   for A in 1 .. Number loop
      if Number rem A = 0 then
         Put (A);
      end if;
   end loop;
end Main;
```